# Create a script that will download a value from text on web pages

Tags: python

I'm looking to capture the highest wind gust value per day from each weather forecast office. I'm not finding any tabular data so I think I need to just create a script that can extract that from the web pages.

E.g. web page: http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=JAN&issuedby=ORD&product=CLI&format=CI&version=5&glossary=0

About halfway down, I just want to capture the "Highest Gust Speed" which for Oct. 30th at this station would be 23 MPH.

Would it be possible to do this with say, Python? I would need to run the script every day to capture the previous day's highest wind gust for all weather stations.

I'm wondering if I could just populate a table with the links to each station and go from there. Thank you.

---

Edited

I pieced together this code that seems to work. I however found this data in txt files that will be easier to deal with. Thank you.

```
import urllib2, csv

url="http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?
site=JAN&issuedby=ORD&product=CLI&format=CI&version=5&glossary=0"

downloaded_data = urllib2.urlopen(url)

#csv_data = csv.reader(downloaded_data)

row2 = ''
for row in downloaded_data:
    row2 = row2 + row

start = row2.find('HIGHEST GUST SPEED   ') + 21
end = row2.find('HIGHEST GUST DIRECTION', start)

print int(row2[start:end])
```

Comment: It's software, so the answer is almost always "yes, it's possible."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are wanting to scrape a web site. In that case I would use python's urllib and beautiful soup lib.

EDIT:

I just check out your link and I don't think beautiful soup really is going to matter in this case. I would still use urllib, but once you get that object, you'll have to parse through that data looking for what you need. It is a bit hacky, but should work. I'll have to check back and see how things came about.

BUT, you could use beautiful soup to extract JUST the plain text to make your plain text parsing a bit easier?. Anyway, just a thought!

Once you get that data, you can create whatever logic you want to check if the previous value is greater than your last pass. Once you figure out that portion, going out and getting the data. Just create a init.d script and forget about it.

```
# example urllib 
def requesturl(self, url):
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = f.read()
    return html

 # beautiful soup
def beautifyhtml(self, html):
    currentprice_id = 'yfs_l84_' + self.s.lower()
    current_change_id = 'yfs_c63_' + self.s.lower()
    current_percent_change_id = 'yfs_p43_' + self.s.lower()
    find = []
    find.append(currentprice_id)
    find.append(current_change_id)
    find.append(current_percent_change_id)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # title of the sites - has stock quote
    #title = soup.title.string
    #print(title)
    # p is where the guts of the information I would want to get
    #soup.find_all('p')
    color = soup.find_all('span', id=current_change_id)[0].img['alt']    
    # drilled down version to get current price:
    found = []
    for item in find:
        found.append(soup.find_all('span', id=item)[0].string)
    found.insert(0, self.s.upper())
    found.append(color)
    return found
```